# WPF change (override) highlight and border color in all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I researched and tested a lot of code before asking this question.

**IDE**: `VS2022`. **OS**: `Windows 11`. **App**: `WPF` `.NET 6` (core) `C#` `T-SQL`

I'm trying to override [SystemColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in a resource dictionary.

I can override this value *successfully*:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
```

The problem is, I'm unable to override the highlight color using the following:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
```

Result:

[image: Colors]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

**Update**:

Using a style did not work.

```
<Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionTextBrush" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

[image: Style]

Comment: TextBox and PasswordBox control their highlight brush via the SelectionTextBrush property. Not all controls use the SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey. SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey is used by the DataGrid for example, but not by the ListBox.

Comment: You would have to create a Style that targets TextBox and PasswordBox in your App.xaml to set the SelectionTextBrush globally.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but adding `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.SelectionTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>` to the XAML returned a run-time error.

Comment: Using a `Style` works 100%, but the problem is that it takes much more XAML code to do so. I was wondering if it's possible to override the system colors because it's easier to do so.

Comment: SelectionTextBrushKey does not exist. Writing the required Style takes three lines of code (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` and `PasswordBox` control their highlight brush via their `SelectionBrush` property. Not all controls use the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`. `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` is used by the `DataGrid` for example, but not by the `ListBox`.

Use `SelectionOpacity` to control the opacity of the highlight brush.

To change the `SelectionBrush` globally you must add a `Style` to the *App.xaml* resources:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionOpacity" Value="0.8" />
  </Style>

  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionOpacity" Value="0.8" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: @Toni The property is SelectionBrush and not SelectionTextBrush. My bad, sorry. The current example should work.

Comment: @Toni SelectionTextBrush sets the foreground color of the selected text.